# Android JsResult onJsAlert when to use confirm and when to use cancel?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Ive just been running through the WebViewDemo for andriod whereby allowing the ability to call native code from Javascript and vice-versa.

```
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
        result.confirm();
        return true;
    }
```

With regards to `result.confirm()`, why or when would you call `confirm` or `cancel`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any difference, you can call either `.confirm()` or `.cancel()` inside `onJsAlert`. In JavaScript, `window.alert()` doesn't return a value, thus it is impossible to figure out in JavaScript, what method has actually been called on the Java side. I guess, `JsResult` is used here just to avoid introducing another dedicated class. If you want to be able to return a boolean value to JavaScript code, use `window.confirm()` and `onJsConfirm`; if you want to return a string, use `window.prompt()` and `onJsPrompt`.